# Proving a random variable has some density function (in general)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose I have some (absolutely continuous?*) r.v $X$ which takes values in some $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose now that the Borel algebra on $S$ can be generated by sets like $T$ (for instance, half-open intervals). Suppose I also know that
$$P(X\in T)=\int_Tf,$$

for every such generating set $T$.

Can I now conclude that $f$ is the density function $f= f_X$?

I would argue the following: since there is a sequence $(T_n)_n$ s.t $B = \bigcup_nT_n$, where all the $T_n$ are disjoint and $B\subseteq S$ (Borel-measurable in $S$) I can write 
\begin{align}
P(X\in B) &= P(X \in \bigcup_nT_n)\\&=\sum_nP(X\in T_n)\\
&=\sum_n\int_{T_n}f\\
&=\int_{\bigcup_nT_n}f=\int_Bf.
\end{align}

*I don't know if the absolute continuity is really necessary.

Comment: You need to be integrating against some measure, which is where absolute continuity comes in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_derivative  ... if the function is not absolutely continuous, you won't have a pdf $f$. If you are new to this material, you should justify interchanging the sum and the integral in the second to last equality in your calculation.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt allright, suppose it is absolutely continuous then. Suppose I am integrating w.r.t the Lebesgue measure, such that the integral possesses all the properties I need for the above calculation. The sum of the integral really follows from the Lebesgue theory then, so this should be fine. Ignoring any other details, (love to hear them though) is the spirit of the argument correct?